# Does the constructor of a class or struct initialize the fields to their default values or not?

Tags: c#, struct

```
class aa{

    public int j=8;
    int f;

    public aa() {
        f=99;
    }

}

struct  bb {

    public int v = 7;
    int l;

    public bb() {
        l = 88;
    }

}
```

I am kind of confused as I am learning about the structs.

let's say if I create an instance of class `aa`, is the field `j` initialized to 8 which is NOT done by the constructor ?  and field `f` is first defaulted to 0, again NOT by the constructor and then initialized to 99 in a constructor

And let's say if I create an instance of struct `bb`, is the `v` initialized to 7 which is NOT done by the constructor? And field `l` is FIRST  defaulted to 0 NOT but the constructor? And then initialized to 88 by the constructor

Comment: Initializers effectively become part of the constructor (*before* any of the statements you explicitly declared), and fields that are not explicitly initialized are initialized to their default values. This knowledge allows you to answer all of your questions. Structs are only special in that their default constructor isn't always invoked, meaning that `var myBB = default(bb)` has all fields initialized to their defaults, regardless of what the initializers and constructor do.

Comment: Your struct doesn't compile.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar: from C# 10 onwards, it will.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Okay, I think I got it, so the fields that are explicitly initialized are initialized to their default values IN the constructor but again _before_  any of the statements i explicitly declare?  You say Initializers effectively become part of the constructor, then how is the object of a struct created if no constructor is called in case of `var myBB = default(bb)` . i mean you said that the initializers become part of the constructor, then how are the fields defaulted?

Comment: When an object is instantiated, the runtime effectively sets aside a piece of memory that it then zeroes out, before any code is run. This is the "initialization" you get if nothing else happens. Note that C# has its own rules for when something is "definitively assigned" that operates separate to, and on top of these rules, so that you may get a "use of possibly unassigned field" error for structs even though the runtime did initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Structure types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#struct-initialization-and-default-values) documentation page describes how structs are initialized. Note that the behavior has changed a bit in recent versions of the language. In C# 11, the compiler ensures that any fields that you do not initialize, either in the constructor or in the field declaration, are assigned their default values.

Also, the [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) documentation page describes how fields in general are initialized:

> A field can be given an initial value by using the assignment operator when the field is declared.

And also:

> Fields are initialized immediately before the constructor for the object instance is called. If the constructor assigns the value of a field, it will overwrite any value given during field declaration.

If your concern is a performance one around fields being initialized twice i.e. once with their initial value assigned as part of their declaration and once in the constructor, then I'd expect the compiler to be smart enough to optimize away any redundant assignments