# Is any code inside the constructor executed when I declare a struct instance?

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

```
struct  bb
{
    public int j = 8;
    public int f;

    public bb()
    {
        f = 88;
    }
}

//main method
bb test;
```

I know that when I *declare* `test` the parameterless constructor *is* called but I am guessing that it is *only* called to initialize the fields to their defaults and create the object but any other code is *not* run like `f=88;`  inside the constructor.

Am I correct?

This pertains to C# 11.

Comment: Why are you guessing? This is [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#struct-initialization-and-default-values), and you can easily write small test programs to verify. Constructors on a `struct` are only invoked explicitly, *not* on declaration. There's no constructor invocation in the above so it won't run. Note that any attempt to *use* `test` will result in an error that `test` is not initialized; `bb test = default` has the same effect without that. The default initialization is done by the runtime; the constructor is not involved.

Comment: Yes, sure, but here I can see that the fields are defaulted using the constructor. So you say thet the fileds are not initialized to their default values through the constructor?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266877/does-the-constructor-of-a-class-or-struct-initialize-the-fields-to-their-default

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I'm saying. For structs, at least, and in this particular case where the constructor isn't getting invoked. I don't know how you think you can "see" that the fields are "defaulted using the constructor". If you decompile this code with something like LINQPad or ILSpy, you can see no such thing is happening -- for `bb = default`, there's an `initobj` instruction and that's it.

Comment: Okay thank you. I mean the first comment to this question says it (The first sentence)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73266877/does-the-constructor-of-a-class-or-struct-initialize-the-fields-to-their-default

Comment: My comment only says "fields that are not explicitly initialized are initialized to their default values". I didn't mean to imply the *constructor* would be doing that, although I see how it could be read that way. Initialization of structs in C# is a little confusing, and has only gotten more confusing now that default constructors have become allowed.

Comment: Okay thank you, I see. But what about   `public int j = 8;`  I mean when I say `bb test;` the `j` is still defaulted. So I am guessing this is the core of your answer that is: if a field is initialized NOT in the constructor like in the code above, then It will be initialized only when the constructor is called if the constructor is not called then It will still be defaulted. Am I correct?

Comment: When you write `bb test;`, to be *very* precise, nothing at all happens because you can't use `test` in any meaningful way (it's unassigned), so the whole variable will normally get optimized away. If you write `bb test = default;`, the compiler emits an `initobj` instruction that will cause the runtime to initialize the fields with all zeroes. *Only* if you write `bb test = new()` does the default constructor get invoked, and that will initialize both `j` and `f`, in that order -- the compiler will fold the initializer for `j` into the constructor body.

Comment: Okay, got it, so when I say `bb test;` No object is even created right since no constructor is called?

Comment: This is an uninitialized variable. Visual Studio will warn you about that when you attempt to use it

Answer (score 1):

you can have [parameterless constructors for structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/parameterless-struct-constructors) but it is not guaranteed that they are called. consider these examples:

```
MyStruct s = default; // no ctor called
MyStruct[] s = new MyStruct[10]; // no ctor for the individual structs called
```

Also if you get your structs from unmanaged code, there will be no constructor call for them.